# Is that a way to come back from " php artisan preset none "?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-artisan

I run `php artisan preset none` without a back up of my previous data, so all my **Vue js** components have been deleted.

So is there anyway to get it back ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19618

Comment: I was just looking for a way to revert that cmd `php artisan preset none`. Unfortunately it looks like https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/19618 doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: you can't get that code back unless if you have it on git somewhere

Comment: Are you committing to a repository? If so, you can `git revert ` or `git reset` https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes

Comment: I guess you'll have to resort to common data recovery utilities. Make sure you don't write to this disk any more until data is restored.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using 6.x version. lewis4u and jeremykenedy unfortunately I did not commit my works on git 4 days before. @EstusFlask I went for recovery utilities but the two main files i was looking for were overwritten. Have to start from my lastest commit on git.